# System.exit(1) exists with return code 0 in multithreaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, exit, java-6

I have a call to `System.exit(1)` in my multi-threaded program. However from time to time instead of return code 1, the program exits with return code 0. I don't have any other calls `System.exit()` and I'm positive that the program doesn't exit cleanly. What can be the cause, and how can I avoid it?

Note that the error is intermittent and I cannot reproduce the same behavior in single threaded programs.

Comment: Can you give any more detail regarding your hunch that the application is not exiting gracefully? Explained behaviour may help people understand what is going on, a little.

Comment: Are there any other System.exit() statements anywhere in the program?

Comment: @ShiDoiSi: There are no other System.exit() in my code (as explained in the quesion)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: It's not a hunch. I am debugging my application deliberately give it bad input which triggers `System.exit(1)`. I do extensive logging to verify the execution path.

Comment: maybe you should post the code.

Comment: @Alexandru: Okay, the request still stands, however, knowing the behaviour you're 'positive' of could well still be informative(?)

Comment: The API documentation for `System.exit(int)` says "Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine.". No ifs or buts about the number of threads present. The API documentation for `Runtime.exit(int)` is much more informative. Does your coide have any shtdown hooks or finalizers? Does it have any calls to `Runtime.halt(int)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Modify your design to execute a more controlled shutdown.**

There should be no expectation that calling `System.exit()` in an application with multiple threads would ever cause the program to exit cleanly.

Rather than calling `System.exit()` to leave the program, you should send shutdown messages to each moving component and use `Thread.join()` to recover any threads you created.  Your application should be able to shut down all pieces nicely this way.  The final command in the main thread should be to return your exit code.  If you just call `System.exit()`, you're leaving all of these shut down details to the JVM, which is just going to take a heavy-handed approach and kill everything on the spot.

Have you used `Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook()` at all?  A call to `System.exit()` will invoke any shutdown hooks that may be installed and this could be changing the exit code.

Comment: I will follow your advice. I use `System.exit(1)` as a shortcut to help me debug.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for Runtime.[halt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#halt%28int%29)(int) says the following about its argument:

> If the exit (equivalently, `System.exit`) method has already been invoked then this status code will override the status code passed to that method.

So perhaps something is invoking `Runtime.halt(int)`. In a shutdown hook or finalizer?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way this may happen if your JVM terminates *before* `System.exit(1)` actually executed. Do you think this may be possible in your system?

Either, the code with `System.exit(1)` is being executed in a daemon thread, and so when all other live (non-daemon) threads finish working JVM exits cleanly (or not cleanly, as you can still get 0 exit code if you program throws an exception!)

Alternatively, as @Erick Robertson suggested, maybe something is modifying the exit status from a hook or something, although I am not sure how this is possible.

Note: please disregard my previous comment. Calling `System.exit(1)` will terminate all currently running daemon/non-daemon threads all-together.